# Battery with 3.7v and 9900mAh , is that enough to know the output current?

Tags: current, raspberry-pi

I have a battery with those specifications: 3.7 V, and 9900 mAh.  From these figures, can I calculate the maximum output current from the battery? I have 2 batteries with those values; can I use them to power a Raspberry Pi 3b? Thanks :)

Comment: You can't know. It should specify maximum discharge current.

Comment: You'll need a boost converter as well.

Comment: Also, if your battery is round, 65mm long and 18mm thick, you've been scammed. There are no batteries with more than 4000mAh in an "18650" form factor. The battery most likely has a capacity of less than 2000mAh.

Comment: @awjlogan : boost converter for raspi ?

Comment: @AlaaOdeh Battery is 3.7 V, RasPi takes a 5 V power supply. Or, precisely, you need 5 V for HDMI and USB.

Comment: @awjlogan he says he has two (Eventually)... so a regular 5V LDO will do fine.

Comment: @Trevor Indeed! Wasting a lot of power though...

Comment: yeah i have a great regulator which will do the job perfectly, this is not my problem , know i know that the output of my batteries is 4.2 v with 650mA so 2 batteries in series ( ignore the regulating to 5v ) can those batteries handle a raspberry pi3 or i need a batteries with higher output current ? @awjlogan

Comment: From here, [WHAT ARE THE POWER REQUIREMENTS?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#topPower), I see \$2.5\:\textrm{A}\$ compliance recommended. If you really are sure you have a true \$9900\:\textrm{mAh}\$ battery (and I wouldn't be certain of it, if I were you), then you can expect a standard draw of about \$\frac{1}{5}\$th of that figure but in Amps, or about \$2\:\textrm{A}\$ draw. I can only say that using two of them isn't instantly excluded, given the right voltage converter. So you should test all this carefully. There are cheap charger/dischargers you can get to test your batteries.

Comment: Lithium batteries will generally try and give you as much current as you ask them for, the catch is some just give up earlier than others. For instance, the vast majority of Ah-class cells are usually capable of supplying their full charge in an hour i.e. a 1Ah (1'000mAh) battery will probably be able to spit out a whole amp while a 9.9Ah battery should probably be able to spit out **up to** 9.9 amps, but doing so might send cheap cells to an early grave. Some can do *MUCH* more though, I've seen cells do **110 times** their Ah rating (i.e. 750A from a 6.6Ah cell), they get *real* hot though

Answer (score 3):

> 3.7 V, and 9900 mAh. From these figures, can I calculate the maximum output current from the battery?

No.

The battery capacity, such as expressed in mAh, tells you how much total charge (current times time) the battery can deliver.  It does not tell you the rate it can deliver that charge in.  That is a separate spec called *maximum current*.

Most batteries can deliver current at least at the 1 hour rate.  This is also often called the "1C" rate.  For your 9.9 Ah battery, that would be 9.9 A.

However, any combination of current and time that comes out to the capacity spec won't work.  You have to read the datasheet carefully.  A 100 mAh battery, for example, can probably deliver 100 mA for 1 hour.  Maybe it can deliver 200 mA for 30 minutes.  However, 6 A for 1 minute is quite unlikely, and 36 A for 10 seconds is absurd.

Comment: Astonishingly enough -- modern RC LiPos are hitting legitimate 60C+ discharges, going from 4.2 to 3.3v in under a minute, while holding 100A or more.  It's supercap levels of discharge current.